# How does OptaPlanner determine when a move is taboo

Tags: optaplanner

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580998/custom-move-implementation) i have asked when the methods "getPlanningEntities" , "getPlanningValues", "hashCode" and "equals" are called in a custom move implementation.

Accordingly "getPlanningEntities" is called when "entity tabu" is present in the solver configuration , "getPlanningValues" when "value tabu" is present in the solver configuration , "hashCode" and "equals" when there is "move/undo tabu".

In my custom move implementation multiple planning variables from different planning entity classes get a new value set.So there are multiple planning entities and multiple planning values.

My question would be how does OptaPlanner determine if a custom move changing multiple planning entities is taboo?

So when it comes to "entity tabu" how will OptaPlanner determine if this custom move is taboo should all the planning entity instances that are changed in this custom move be present in the taboo list or just one of the instances being present in the taboo list will make this move taboo?

Then when it comes to "value tabu" i would ask the same question will the move be taboo if the taboo list contains at least one value that the custom move tries to set to a planning variable , or all the variables should be in the taboo list for the move to be declared as taboo?

Also when combining the "entity tabu" and "value tabu" together in the solver configuration how will a move be declared as taboo should all the planning entities and planning variables be present in the lists , or just one planning entity , or one planning variable , or one planning entity and one planning variable?

Then when it comes to the "move tabu" i think its clear the tabu list is consisted from hash values and if a move with the same hash appears then it is taboo.But if a different custom move (instance from a different move class) produces the same hash value will it be counted as taboo , or not because it is not an "instanceof" the same custom move class and the "equals" method would return false?